# Javascript calling a private method with ()() - parentheses after parentheses

Tags: javascript, oop, private-methods

I was playing with private methods and I have accidentally found out, that I can call a method, which calls a private method using ()() - double parentheses instead of assigning it to variables  couple of times. 
Here is my code to make it clearer:

```
function Person(name, age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    var bankBalance = 7500;
    var returnBalance = function() {
        return bankBalance;
    };
    this.askTeller = function() {
        return returnBalance;
    }
}

var john = new Person('John', 'Smith', 30);

console.log(john.returnBalance); // undefined

var myBalanceMethod = john.askTeller();
var myBalance = myBalanceMethod();
console.log(myBalance); // 7500

console.log(john.askTeller()()); // 7500 (same result but one line instead of three
```

So, is that - ()() syntax valid?

Comment: Clearly it is - your code runs.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about JavaScript syntax checking, which can easily be accomplished using a linter such as http://jslint.com or http://jshint.com.

Comment: Your critical mistake is thinking that JavaScript has private methods. Just because you define a function and assign it to a var doesn't mean that you can't return that var to a higher scope and call the function.

Comment: Valid - but pretty ugly. Ideally `this.askTeller` would return `returnBalance()` and not `returnBalance`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep it is - `john.askTeller()` returns the function `returnBalance` that you then invoke with `()`.

`returnBalance` is a function scoped to the `Person` *constructor* function, but it is made available outside of this scope when it is returned from the `askTeller` function call.